# Site search and categories

Tags: category, layered-navigation, search, navigation

Site search results:

These cats are not needed to show here as they show in properly below them (in the attributes). I have made them 'non active' in the category sections all bar the product type, phone type and manufacturer as they are in the navigation menu. Is there a way to get rid of these 3 remaining cats from the side narrow down whilst keeping them the nav at the top of the site?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it the objective is to remove the Category section from the Layered navigation sidebar completely? If so you can simply remove the block from the page completely by putting the following into your themes `local.xml` file.

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="catalog.leftnav">  
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

**UPDATE:** To remove from the search results page, simply use a different layout handle:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="catalog.leftnav">  
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cags. I will need to retain the category section for normal nav, but need to remove it for Site Search results. Please see the bottom image above i have just added.

Comment: I updated my answer.